# Dynamic parameters in USING clause PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, plsql, procedure

I have a question, I'm building a PLSQL code to execute any procedure or function the dynamic way.
I'm using a metadata table to know which element sql I'll execute this way.

Process some codes to recover informations to build a similar block:

```
V_COMMAND := 'BEGIN PROC_EX(:1,:2,:3,:4); END;';
```

But the problem is in apply the command execute immediate because I need bind variable in clause USING the dynamic way. I tried to create a String variable that storage all parameters but when I executed I received a ora error `ORA-01008`.

I created a temporary var to storage params:

```
V_PARAMS := 'IN P_TABLE, IN P_WHERE, OUT O_MESSAGE, OUT O_CODE';
```

where:
`P_TABLE`, `P_WHERE`, `O_MESSAGE` and `O_CODE` are variables declared at begin code.

And I executed the command this way:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_COMMAND USING V_PARAMS;
```

Is it possible mapping variable the dynamic way in using clause?

Comment: Thanks for edit my question, I don't know way I not change text to code style.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [DBMS_SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68199)

Example of usage that fits your needs:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE foo (n NUMBER, square OUT NUMBER) IS
      BEGIN square := n * n; END;/

      CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bulk_plsql 
         (n DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE, square OUT DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE) IS
      c NUMBER;
      r NUMBER;
      BEGIN
        c := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
        DBMS_SQL.PARSE(c, 'BEGIN foo(:bnd1, :bnd2); END;', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
        DBMS_SQL.BIND_ARRAY(c, 'bnd1', n);
        DBMS_SQL.BIND_ARRAY(c, 'bnd2', square);
        r := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c);
        DBMS_SQL.VARIABLE_VALUE(c, 'bnd2', square);
     END;
     /
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.